# Google Page Speed Error - Lighthouse returned error: This request took too long to render

Tags: pagespeed, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights, google-pagespeed-insights-api

Recently I run a page speed report of my website "https://www.globalvincitore.com/", as its part of SEO. But they returned "Lighthouse returned an error: This request took too long to render." this kind of error msg.

[Google Page Speed Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNJZf.png)

[GTMetrix Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfqCC.png)

Now I am wondering, Why My website Because I check in different device with cache clearing. On all of those devices, my website is completely running.

Can you please help me find the exact issues?

Note: not only in "page speed insights" but in " GTMetrix" also shown the same error.

Comment: It's simple your website is taking too long to load , make sure you don't have larg paintings (pictures , videos ) use compressed Media to reduce loading time and  run the test again then google will show you the rest of the errors you have in your site

Comment: hotjar tends to cause this. I don't know what it is about their implementation using web sockets but PSI doesn't like it. Switch hotjar off and run the test, it will probably work.

Comment: Removed Hotjar, Still Face the same situation. After cleaning catch also

Comment: Already compressed media, but still face the same issue

Comment: Look for anything else using websockets. You have `tawk` whatever that is that also looks to have the same behaviour.

Comment: For the last 2.5 years, we have Tawk & this issue is started just 1 week ago. I don't think tawk code is creating a problem here.